# How to get id of hovered element in tooltip widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

How can I get hovered element **id** in tooltip widget?

I'm trying to post **id** to php file and get tooltip content associated with posted **id**

```
$(document).tooltip({

    items:'.tooltip',
    content: "wait, please...",
    open: function(event, ui) {

        var _elem = ui.tooltip;
        $.ajax({
             url: '/tooltip.php',
             data: { lang: '<?php echo $lang['language'];?>', id:**HOVERED ELEMENT ID** },
             type: 'post',
             success: function(data) {
                 //hacky, but works! :)
                _elem.find(".ui-tooltip-content").html(data);
             },
         });
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an access through the event target:

```
open: function(event, ui) {
  var el = event.originalEvent.target;
  alert('Id is' + $(el).attr('id'));
```

In case it does not work in IE use below code:

```
var el = $(event.originalEvent.target || event.originalEvent.srcElement).closest($(this).tooltip('option', 'items'))[0];
```

Comment: Thanks it is works.  Just need to change  `alert('Id is' + $(el).attr('id'));`

Answer (score 0):

Check for scope issues of `ui` just in case, otherwise:

`var id = ui.item.attr('id')`;